# Building Desktop apps by JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to create an application for desktop computers.

And I want to use the Power of JQuery Mobile.

But by default, JQuery adds each control on a row. it looks nice in a mobile phone, like the image below:

[image]

But it will be ugly in big screens:

[image]

My question is: **Is there any way to design application with JQuery Mobile, multi-column style?**

**And how to create Horizontally scroll applications with JQuery Mobile?** (I mean, just like windows 8 metro apps that don't have vertical scroll in pages. they have horizontal scroll in pages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Mobile works very well with desktop, too. Just use a [grid](http://cssgrid.net/) to structure your content.

I think the real advantage of jQuery Mobile will sooner or later be, that you only need to write something once and can deploy on every device from desktop to tablet to smartphone to whatever. Although there is some way to go for jQuery Mobile, this would be the direction I would want to it develop into.

There are a bunch of horizontal scroll plugins available. Try JQuery Mobile [pagaintion](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jqm-pagination/demo/) for pages,[photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) for images or [overthrow](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/) for content.

Comment: Thanks, but `overthrow` seems to have vertical scroll, not horizontal scroll. I want horizontal scrolling, just like Windows 8 metro menu...

Comment: @Mahdi: I'm using it both ways. Works just fine. Just assign class overthrow to an element, fix it's width (to say 200px) and have nested elements with larger width (say 1000px). And it scrolls

Comment: Still in 1.4, because navbar widget uses it. You could have a look at css table-layout:fixed

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good idea to use Jquery mobile for desktop apps. Instead it's a good idea to write the desktop app using Jquery UI and mobile app using JQuery mobile. Depending on the client type (mobile or desktop), use appropriate library and render the response.

You might want to look at Haxe http://haxe.org/ which supports multiple platforms. You might find it interesting to write application in one language and cross-compile to many other target platforms/languages.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Layout Grids. The Demo is provided here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: jqm also has responsive grids (scroll to the bottom of the link)

Answer (score 1):

I have had some experiments building HTML5 apps as desktop applications, using Python to create a webkit window and embedding the web site in it. I recommend you to use JQuery if you want, but JQuery or JQuery UI, not JQuery Mobile, because it has been designed for touch devices, no for desktop environments. What does jQuery Mobile give you for desktop that JQuery UI doesn't?

Comment: My goal is to create a cross-platform application for desktop and mobile phones, with a responsive JQuery Mobile UI...

Comment: You can use JQuery Mobile, although you don't need it. You have to learn to do responsive designs, whether you use JQuery Mobile or not. Responsibe design is more related to CSS than with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could mimic the jQM demo site for the two column approach

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/about/intro.html

And for scrolling you could use something like this

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/experiments/scrollview/
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html ( Horizontal Scrolling )