# Are Ajax requests on mobile slower than Desktop requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the latest versions of iOS Chrome and Mac OSx Chrome, but this is a general question. It seems like ajax request-heavy websites perform ajax calls 2 times faster than their mobile counterparts. Why is that? Presuming they are both the same websites with the same ajax request

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144077/javascript-jquery-runs-fast-in-desktop-browsers-but-slow-in-mobile-smartphone-b

Answer (score 0):

I think it has more to do with the request and rendering time of the device rather than a response from the server.

But you'd have to do some javascript benchmarking to really nail it down.